# How do you modify block comment alignment in Intellij IDEA with Scala?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, comments, scaladoc

Currently when Intellij IDEA autocompletes block comments, e.g. typing `/**+<return>`, IDEA will create a block comment like so:

`/**
  * Comment goes here
  */`

However, scaladoc recommends that block comment bodies are aligned differently:

`/**
 * Comment here
 */`

(Note the whitespace difference).

How is this configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see support for this in IntelliJ; I think if it was there, it would be under `Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Java > JavaDoc`. Even though it says JavaDoc, changing these settings also affects Scala and ScalaDoc code.

I'd recommend using [Scalariform](https://github.com/daniel-trinh/scalariform) to achieve this. Scalariform is a code formatter that will format you code on compile, regardless of what you type into IntelliJ. It has a setting called [placeScaladocAsterisksBeneathSecondAsterisk](https://github.com/daniel-trinh/scalariform#placescaladocasterisksbeneathsecondasterisk) which is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Intellij 2018.2 supports this now by default.

The setting is at `Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Scala > ScalaDoc > Use ScalaDoc indent for leading asterisk`.

Comment: Works with intellij IDE 2017.3 too.